# Unable to decide Java collection

Tags: java, collections

My usecase is like in which I need to maintain a collection of unique items. I may need to frequently add or remove items from the collection at an index(which I have as member of the item currently, but I am open to modification), and while doing that I need to update index of items.

I am not able to decide which Java collection would suit my needs best. HashSet and SortedSet both guarantee uniqueness, but not sure how index part can be taken care of.

Comment: Do you need to enforce uniqueness, or do the elements happen to be unique already?

Comment: A Set seems the way to go, but they don't offer access by index. Why do you need that? If you could describe your *actual* need, there might be a way.

Comment: Elements are unique. BTW, how does it impact the choice?

Comment: Basically I am designing a sort of scrapbook wherein people can add or remove the images. They must be able to do so at any specific position they want.

Comment: Use a hash set. Let the key be whatever index you need and the value is going to be your item. This approach seems pretty common for your stated case.

Comment: What is key in context of HashSet?

Comment: [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is what I thought but did not type. In the future, if you want to address a comment directly, type @<username> and the user will see a notification. If I hadn't been ruminating on whether I recommended the correct data structure, I would never have seen your comment.

Comment: Does removing or adding an item at an index mean having to modify the índices of all the other items? What are the constraints on modifications to the indexed

Comment: @Joni, yes that's what I want. So, user would like to add 5 images at index, say 10. So after insertion, added images would have index 10,11,12,13,14 while older images from 10 onwards would have their index incremented by 5. So originally 
 index 10 image now has index 15, and so on.Same goes for removal.

Comment: How about adding or removing at an index that's out of bounds, should that throw an exception? So basically the same behavior as ArrayList but with a uniqueness constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question + comments, you have the following fundamental requirements for the collection:

1. The elements in the collection must be unique.
2. The collection must maintain the elements in an order specified by the user.
3. The collection elements must have unique indexes representing the element's current position.
4. The indexes must adjust as elements are inserted and deleted.

There is no (single) Java SE collection type that does 1 and 2, 3 or 4.

The only Java SE collection type that supports and can maintain an arbitrary ordering is `List`, so you need to start with that.  Something like this for instance:

```
public class MyList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void add(int pos, <E> e) {
        if (this.contains(e)) {
            throw new SomeException("already in collection");
        }
        this.add(pos, e);
    }
}
```

---

Note that `HashMap<Integer, E>` is a possible alternative, but adjusting the indexes as elements are added and removed is *complicated*.  (Comparing the performance characteristics is not straightforward, but the chances are that it won't matter in your use-case.)

Comment: Don’t subclass `ArrayList`. Subclass `AbstractList` and delegate to an `ArrayList`. Otherwise, you’ll constantly fail to catch all ways to add to the list. `addAll` or `listIterator().add(…)`, just to name two examples.